# github api: how to get clones?

Tags: api, github, curl, credentials

I'm trying to get clones with ([from here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-clones)):

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/{myname}/{myrep}/traffic/clones
```

However, I get this error:

```
"message": "Must have push access to repository"
```

I even tried:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token {mytoken}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/{myname}/{myrep}/traffic/clones
```

but I get the same error...

I used the old API version and it was easy and quick, and I cannot find a working solution... what am I missing?

(I would like to use curl since I use this command in a sh file)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl \
-H "Authorization: token bade46eb8b548dcb47c4a3263492faa7fb857d83" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repository name}/traffic/clones
```

This command works with the new API

*(the token is fake, but useful for people to have a general idea of how it looks)*